# How can I jail users to their home directory with mod_userdir in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, ldap

I need to make my users' home directories available to them over the web. I have LDAP authentication in place so only valid users can access the home directories but currently a valid user can access any given home directory. I want to jail users to their own home directory. Is this possible with Apache?

Comment: Just to be clear, when say jail, "/~joebob" is only accessible to the user joebob, but joebob could not go to "/~thomvu"?

Comment: Correct. I'm aware of the Apache variable REMOTE_USER but I'm not sure how, if I'm even able to, use that to keep users in their own directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use vhost-alias, to deliver the user in their directory after authentication, and they won't be able to go into anyones else's directory.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to use %{remote_user} with this setup?

Comment: I don't have the capability to use wildcard subdomains for this setup so I wasn't able to fully implement this solution. However, it looks like this would be the best course of action.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are looking for the directive `UserDir`

```
UserDir public_html
```

This will have apache look for `public_html`.

For example

```
http://example.com/~username/index.html
```

will look for the file `/home/username/public_html/index.php`

Comment: I am currently using the UserDir directive and I have it set to /home so that users can browse through their files within their home directories. However, once a user has been authenticated they can access everyone's home directories. I want to make it so that they can only access their own home directory.